# What should I do about a huge compiled list of claims?

Tags: discussion, scope, questions

So, I just read an article (on cracked.com) that has between 20 and 100 claims, depending on how granular one goes, most of which at first glance seem interesting enough to want to test them for accuracy via Skeptics.SE collective brain.

On one hand, the claims are largely dis-jointed, so they don't seem to belong in the same question(s) combined.

On the other hand, i'm a little worried about posting 20 to 100 individual questions. Is that Kosher? Welcome?

Some claims come with prooflinks of one study (meaning, asking if other studies support the conclusion), while others don't have a link.

Comment: Are any of the claims already well-cited (you mention "prooflinks")? If so, perhaps a question isn't necessary for those. Are any of them duplicates of pre-existing questions? What kind of article is it? Because 20 truly discrete, noteworthy, and controversial claims in a single article strikes me as high? Is it a listicle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Please don't put them all in one question. That makes it nigh impossible to answer, even when you have great evidence for or against one of the claims. Multiple questions are preferred.
- Please consider spending a few minutes on each claim yourself to see if the Internet already has a good answer. If the top hit on the obvious search words lead to a reliable source supporting or rejecting the claim, then there isn't much value in having the Skeptics.SE Collective brain work on it.
- Generally, I would recommend starting with only one claim, and giving it a few days before asking any more, so we can quickly fix any systemic problems with the questions. However, you know the site as well as anyone, and I am confident your first question will be on-topic, so this advice isn't really applicable.
- I think you will get a better response if you trickle the questions out at one every day or two. If you blast them all at once, they may not all get the attention they deserve.

Comment: The system also [gives you badges](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/98/socratic) if you ask enough questions (that get upvoted) on *separate* days.

Comment: @Laurel - I already won the badge game (I have every reasonably achievable badge on a site, only missing "100-favorites question" and "Illuninator"; I have 3 gold tag badges and 100+ gold badges total. The gamification lost its hold on me :)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say having not seen the article.  I wouldn't just broadly put up every claim you read in the article, for a number of reasons.

1. Any claim that is just 'Is this a real picture?' is going to be removed.
2. Any claim that is cited with research journals isn't going to attract high quality answers because you've already done the job of answerers.
3. Any claim that has already been asked is going to be flagged as a duplicate and removed
4. Anything about current ongoing events will be closed per

> Questions about unresolved current events and issues currently under investigation by a court of law, government, or other similar investigative body are off-topic because there is insufficient data for a meaningful answer. For more information, see Handling current news questions.

5. If the article is a listicle (see [Luigi Gets A Bulge (And Other News That’s Weird AF)](http://www.cracked.com/article_25533_luigi-gets-bulge-and-other-news-thatE28099s-weird-af.html) on the home page right now) many of those images are submitted by readers, not by the writers of Cracked, and therefore can't be held to the same standard of notability as an actual article
6. Cracked already has a pretty well acknowledged history of exaggerating claims or embellishing stories in order to make an article more entertaining and shouldn't be held to the same standards as other notable sources.

---

What you should do is prune down the claims first.  If you're having trouble with it, I would recommend you post the article to get more specific advice.